# How do I call a c function on each occurrence in LoadRunner?

Tags: performance, user-defined-functions, loadrunner, parameterization

So there is this HUGE JSON that I am loading from a file and than I run it through lr_eval_string and save it to a parameter. This parameter is later used as a body in one of my REST calls.

I use lr_eval_string to dynamically replace different values in that JSON. 
Now here is the problem, one of the values that I replace is unique and generated by a c function. This value appears numerous times in that JSON and needs to be unique each time, yet I am only able to call that c function once at the beginning of the action. The result is that all values end up being equal...

So my question is: how can I call my function each time this unique value appears? I am talking about functionality similar to "Update value on: Each occurrence" that is available on the Parameters section.

I see an option called "User Defined Function" in parameters which I guess could do what I am looking for yet I couldn't find any good tutorial on how to actually use this functionality. Is user defined action the way to go, is there any other solution?
Any help would be highly appreciated! :)

Comment: see sprintf() for the concatenation of strings which may include the output of a function which itself is a string.

Comment: I think you are approaching this in a wrong way. Do you mind contacting our COST team?